# screen looks like pushed toward left and up when rotating it in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Window have empty space in right and bottom about 3cm. It looks like the screen had pushed away. I rotate my screen to reference [this page](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-rotate-image/).

Here is picture

[image]

```
import cv2 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #return 0 or -1
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, img = cap.read()
    h,w = img.shape[:2]
    center =  (w/2, h/2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 90, 1)
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (h, w)) 
    #flip the image vertically
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)


    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break 
    if not ret: 
        print('no camera connected!') 

    cv2.imshow('camera-0', img)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the line `img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (h, w))` where `h` and `w` must be interchanged.

The function `cv2.warpAffine()` creates a new image with the rotation matrix `M`. But since `w` and `h` have been interchanged the resulting frame appears to have been translated resulting in the black region.

Replace the above line with `img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h))`

The resulting output of this code would result in the opposite ends being chopped off. To know how to rotate images properly (without chopping edges) you **must** have alook at [THIS BLOG](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/)